# Modify component schema data value with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, aframe

```js
AFRAME.registerComponent("myComponent", {
    schema: {
        myVar: {
            type: "string",
            default: "default value"
        }
    },
    init: function () {
        var self=this;
        
        this.data.myVar="test";
        console.log(this.data.myVar); // "test"
        
        this.el.addEventListener("myEvent", function () {
            console.log(self.data.myVar); // "default value"
        });

    }
});
```

I want to modify value of data component but, while I'm in an event, I only get the default value.

How to do it ?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://aframe.io/docs/0.8.0/introduction/javascript-events-dom-apis.html#updating-a-component-with-setattribute

```
el.setAttribute('myComponent', 'myVar', value)
```